# To-Many Relationships get specific List Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, list, xamarin.android, realm

Hello I'm learning Realm in Xamarin,

Im trying to get a specific List from Realm.
On the main page i have a RecyclerView and i want to show different list items for the different RecyclerView Items. But how can i get the lists?

Realm Object:

```
public class StufeAd : RealmObject
{

    public string mName { get; set; }
    public int mPhoto { get; set; }
    public int mDurchschnitt { get; set; }
    public IList<F> mItemlist { get; }
}

public class F : RealmObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

Item add:

```
var ad = realm.All<StufeAd>().Where(m => m.mName == name).First();

var a = new F { Name = "Test", Id = 11 }; // Input

mFliste.Add(fach);

realm.Write(() =>
{
    ad.mItemlist.Add(a);
});

mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now i want to get the the list only where i added the items.

[RecyclerView, with the FAB i can add more cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4haAg.png)

[First List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Zmz.png)

Each Lists shows exactly the same.

Comment: Can you add some example input and expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to add items dynamically to the already loaded list?

Comment: Added example and yes dynamically

Comment: `ad.mItemList` would be the list where you added the items - are you asking how to get it if you don't have reference to `ad` or?

Comment: I'm slightly confused what you're trying to achieve, the explanation isn't that clear. When you add items to the database in the `Write()` call. They are only existing in the database list. You need to add the item to the list that feeds the RecyclerView as well. Then refresh the recyclerview.